# Как адекватно перевести английское слово starring?

Tags: английский-язык, переводы

А английском языке есть слово *starring*. Его пишут в титрах фильма, и смысл у него близок к русскому "в главных ролях", но не совсем. Потому что тут именно "звездят", то есть, скорее, "звезды в главных ролях". И вот встал вопрос как-то адекватно перевести это слово на русский язык. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сформулировать? Хорошо было бы одним словом, но можно словосочетанием, только не длинным.

Comment: *Теоретически* здесь есть отдельный форум **"Английский язык"**.

http://english.sezn.ru/

:-) А *практически* туда последнее время почти никто не ходит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Русский язык скромнее английского. Если актеры действительно звезды, то в дополнительном указании на статус их имя не нуждается. Так что "в главных ролях" вполне подойдет. Да и слово "звездить" уже занято под не очень литературный синоним слова "обманывать".

Comment: "Русский язык скромнее английского" странно такое читать на сайте разбирающихся в языках, так как - это английский язык скромнее русского. Не говоря уже о современном словоупотреблении. Одно "to get" чего стОит.

Answer (score 6):

"В главных ролях" или "в фильме снимались", и "в фильме также снимались" – все очень просто.

Answer (score 3):

"В главных ролях". Ведь именно это и подразумевается. Перевод - дело тонкое. Одно и тоже понятие разных языках может по-разному выражаться. То, что у нас - "в главных ролях", у них - "starring".

Answer (score 2):

А Вы поставьте перед собой задачу не "адекватно" перевести, а точно, как это и было всегда в советской школе перевода. Тогда проблема сама собой и отпадёт, так как точный перевод - это "в главных ролях", потому что "to star" - это "исполнение главной роли" даже актером-новичком.

Comment: Кстати, а это точно форум РУССКОГО языка? Наличие такого подраздела русистики, как "английский язык", окончательно подтверждает подчиненное положение современного "русского" языка и постепенное его превращение в англо-американский диалект.

Comment: >Потому что "to star"  
  
Это не так. Это - сниматься в любой роли (преимущественно конечно в главной) но в качестве звезды, раскрученного актера...

Answer (score 2):

Если "адекватно" переводить, то звездят.

А если серьезно, то как понятие - в ролях звезды (такие-то).
Ну а если такое вдруг всплвыло в титрах фильма, то вообще не надо переводить, ибо это не в традициях русского кинематографа. У нас просто - "в главных ролях", "в ролях", "в эпизодах"... Под этими категориями и надо представлять актеров.

Возможно впоследствии будет найдена или принята общепринятая конструкция для обозначения понятия на русском.

Answer (score 1):

Однословного соответствия нет. 
Starring (блистающий) - причастие от star (звезда). Лучшее приближение: в фильме блистает (звездой).., смысл связан с рекламой на имени известности (звезды), но не привязан к главной роли.